# DAT1 dopamine and cocaine binding

Tags: protein-binding, dopamine, cocaine

I've searched the internet for several minutes and I've looked at DAT but I'm having trouble finding the DAT binding location. Where (and to which aa) does dopamine and cocaine bind to hDAT1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following paper answers your question in detail:

> http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18568020

It seems like the following aa are responsible for the binding, but please refer to the paper for more details:

> Val152,Tyr156,Asn157,Ser422,(Asp79)